# Excel auto save macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I am trying to create a macro that auto-saves my excel workbook whenever the value in a specific cell increases by 1.

I have the code for the auto-save whenever the cell changes which I will post below;

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A2")) Is Nothing Then
        ThisWorkbook.Save
    End If
End Sub
```

However, I can't seem to adapt the code for the macro to only execute when the value in the cell increases by one. I.e, cell value is 10, only save workbook when the cell value is 11 and so forth.

Thank you.

Comment: Does cell **A2** contain a *formula* or a *typed constant*?

Comment: Nope. The Excel sheet is connected to an Access Database and that's where it's getting the values from.

Comment: Not an Expert on VBA but i think if you create a Table out of your connection to Access DB in your Excel sheet and put the connection under 'Add to Data Model' then you may be able to fire Worksheet_TableUpdate event every time the data is refreshed from the Access DB. The initial value of intended cell can be stored in a Public Global variable at Workbook_Open() event and accessed subsequently for comparison in Worksheet_TableUpdate event that would fire every time the table is refreshed from Access DB.

Comment: The problem I have is that the Macro I have is supposed to fire only when the cell A2 changes, but since I have Excel connected to Access, and on automatic updates (Which is mandatory), everytime the data refreshes the Macro detects as a cell change and auto saves, which then fires another script that I'm using for work and that won't do. I need excel to auto save only when cell "A2" is 1 number higher than before. So like count or auto-increment, not sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code and revert back in case of any issues.  Small assumption or constraint is that the sheet has been  refreshed at least once from the database and the existing contents are not deleted thereafter, just refreshed again as and when needed.  In case if you clear the data after save and before close and then open a blank sheet every time a different solution would be needed.

ALT + F11 --> VBA Editor --> ThisWorkbook --> General --> Declarations

```
Public Prev_Val As Variant
```

Workbook_Open() event

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   ThisWorkbook.Prev_Val = Sheet1.Range("A2").Value
End Sub
```

Under Sheet1 or whatever is your Sheet Codename - Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) event. Replace Sheet1 by whatever is the Sheet Codename be it Sheet1 or Sheet2 or so.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A2")) Is Nothing Then
    If Sheet1.Range("A2").Value = ThisWorkbook.Prev_Val + 1 Then
        ThisWorkbook.Save

    End If
    ThisWorkbook.Prev_Val = Sheet1.Range("A2").Value
End If

End Sub
```

Now when you open the Workbook, the Public variable Prev_Val stores the value in A2 and uses it subsequently for comparison and keeps updating this value to whatever is the latest update in A2, till you sloe the Workbook.

Comment: Hey! Thank you for the reply. I am currently trying the code and I will let you know how it goes. Just out of curiosity, if I wanted to change the autosave of the workbook from when Prev_Val is one higher (+1) to autosave whenever the the new value is higher than the previous value (Something like If new_val > prev_val then Thisworkbook.Save. Would that be possible?

Comment: Edit: I can't test if the code works because when I run the script on the xlsm file that I have connected to my access database, the database stops updating, it isn't writing any values from the main server DB to it. Strange. Maybe I have made a bad connection. I will test further

Comment: Edit Nr.2: I got it to work however, everytime Excel refreshes from Access it still auto-saves anyway. I have tested the code and it works fine, if I change for example, 10 to 9 it doesn't save, if I change 10 to 11 in cell A2 it does save, and that's how its supposed to be, but again, everytime it auto-refreshes through ODBC from Access it auto-saves regardless. Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Ok. Do check if you have ThisWorkbook.Save or such code entered in any other event just in case something like Worksheet_TableUpdate event or any other.

Comment: Edit Nr.3: I changed the code and it seems to be fully working as intended. The only thing I changed was   If Sheet1.Range("A2").Value = ThisWorkbook.Prev_Val + 1 Then to If Me.Range("A2").Value > ThisWorkbook.Prev_Val Then. I think it will work better for my case. Either I will keep testing and I will post further. Thank you for leading me in the right direction!

Comment: Last edit. I Selected your reply as a solution. Everything is working fine. Thank you again :)